# The 'onkey' method in always executing in python and does not require the keystroke?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In the snake program (Python), the line my_screen.onkey(my_snake.turn_up(), 'Up')  is always executing. It triggers this 'Up' keystroke event irrespective of the my_screen.listen() statement or if i have pressed any keys ! Can someone help please as I am unable to get this to run properly, ie it was always run the onkey event 'Up'.

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
import time
my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
my_screen.bgcolor("black")
my_screen.title("My Snake Game")
'''this causes the screen to stop updating, until it gets the 'Update' function call'''
my_screen.tracer(0)
'''create turtle objects'''
my_snake = Snake()
print(my_snake.segments)
my_screen.listen()
my_screen.onkey(my_snake.turn_up(), 'Up')
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    my_screen.update()
    time.sleep(.1)
    my_snake.move()
my_screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `onkey()` command must have a function without braces `()`. So you could have written as

```
my_screen.onkey(my_snake.turn_up, 'Up')
```

instead of

```
my_screen.onkey(my_snake.turn_up(), 'Up')
```